# How to convert time from 24 hour format to 12 hour format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

The function returns the time in 24 hour format.

```
function fomartTimeShow(h) {
    return h < 10 ? "0" + h + ":00" : h + ":00";
}
```

returns the time in 24 hour format. I want the time to be converted in 12 hour format.
Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So `h` is just an integer between 0 and 23? What have you tried?

Comment: If you do a lot of date/time parsing, it might be interesting to check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use modulus 12:

```
function formatTimeShow(h_24) {
    var h = h_24 % 12;
    return (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + ':00';
}
```

Modulus (`%`) means divide and take remainder. For example 17 / 12 = 1 with remainder 5. So the result of 17 % 12 is 5. And hour 17 is hour 5 in 12-hour time.

But note that this function is not complete since it doesn't work for hour 0 (or hour 12). To fix it you have to add in another check for that:

```
function formatTimeShow(h_24) {
    var h = h_24 % 12;
    if (h === 0) h = 12;
    return (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + ':00';
}
```

Also note that you can add a meridian easily, by seeing whether the hour is less than 12 (am) or equal to/greater (pm):

```
function formatTimeShow(h_24) {
    var h = h_24 % 12;
    if (h === 0) h = 12;
    return (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + ':00' + (h_24 < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
}
```

*Note: All of the above is assuming the parameter to this function is an integer between 0 and 23.*

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following:

```
function fomartTimeShow(h) { 
    var ampm = "am"
    if (h >= 12)
        ampm = "pm"
    h = h % 12;
    if (h == 0)
     h = 12;
    return h ":00" + ampm; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work right for midnight or noon. It will show "00:00am" and "00:00pm" for these. You should check for to see if the value is "0" and replace that with "12".

Comment: After `h = h % 12;`, `h` will never be `>= 12`.

Comment: Thanks Ben Lee and M42, you're both correct. I've amended the code the reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fomartTimeShow(h) {
    var s = (h % 24 < 12) ? "am" : "pm", h = h % 12 || 12;
    return (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h)  + ":00" + " " + s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are getting time like this **"16:26", "12:50", "05:23"**, etc.
Then, you can easily convert them into 12 hour format like **"4:26 PM", "12:50 PM", "05:23 AM"**, etc. with AM/PM through this function.

```
function convertTo12Hour(oldFormatTime) {
    console.log("oldFormatTime: " + oldFormatTime);
    var oldFormatTimeArray = oldFormatTime.split(":");

    var HH = parseInt(oldFormatTimeArray[0]);
    var min = oldFormatTimeArray[1];

    var AMPM = HH >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    var hours;
    if(HH == 0){
      hours = HH + 12;
    } else if (HH > 12) {
      hours = HH - 12;
    } else {
      hours = HH;
    }
    var newFormatTime = hours + ":" + min + " " + AMPM;
    console.log(newFormatTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will work as an even more concise formulaic version of Ben Lee's answer, including for the h=0 and h=12 cases:

```
function fomartTimeShow(h_24) {
    var h = ((h_24 + 11) % 12)+1;
    return (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + ':00';
}
```

or including am/pm:

```
function fomartTimeShow(h_24) {
    var h = ((h_24 + 11) % 12)+1;
    return (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + ':00' + (h_24 < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Javascript function to convert 24 hour to 12 hour but unlike all the other answers on this question, this one is easy to read.

```
function timeTo12(time){

  var parts = time.split(':');
  var hours = parseInt(parts[0]);
  var minutes = parts[1];

  if(hours >= 12){
    var newhours = parseInt(hours) - 12;
    var meridiem = "pm";
  }else{
    var newhours = parseInt(hours);
    var meridiem = "am";
  }

  if(newhours == 0) newhours = "12";
  var newtime = newhours + ":" + minutes + " " + meridiem;

  return newtime;
}
```